# Install webextension on Firefox for Android from a website

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to install an unlisted webextension on Firefox for Android from a website but it keeps blocking it, even though it is signed (preliminarily reviewed).
I can only install it, by going to Mozilla's website, downloading it and installing it immediately. Not even if I run it from a file manager.

Do I need a custom certificate or something?
Thank you.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution

Comment: So, are you saying that even when you use "Save Link As" to save the *.xpi* file from the install button on AMO and then drag and drop the resulting file onto Firefox it does not install? Note: After the drag & drop, you may then need to click on the Firefox window to bring it into focus prior to the install dialog appearing.

Comment: @Makyen You mean on "Firefox for Android" or just Firefox?

Comment: You are correct what I described was visualizing desktop Firefox. However, the issues I was attempting to get at are valid for Firefox on Android: A) Have you tried the installation method you want to be working with other extensions? In other words, have you reduced this problem to an issue specific to your add-on, or is it an issue for all add-ons in the configuration in which you are testing? B) If it is just your add-on, are you sure you are using a version of your add-on's *.xpi* file that is sourced from AMO, (i.e. you are sure you are testing with the signed *.xpi* package)?

Comment: This question, at its basic, is a debugging question (i.e. *Why is X not working the way I want*). For such questions to be on-topic, they need to include enough info for us to duplicate the issue. At min, duplication can be used to verify a solution, needed even if we have a *guess* as to the problem. While it is difficult to attach a *signed* *.xpi*, it would be helpful to include a link to the add-on in the question. As it is, the only duplication we can attempt is installing a random add-on to see if it works, which is something you should have already done and mentioned in the question.

Comment: Have you tried setting `xpinstall.whitelist.required` in `about:config` to `false`?  While forcing your potential users to have to set this option is not a solution, testing this may help point you in the direction of where the problem lies.